# Watch model in Angular without replacing it's initial value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to place a watch on an input to perform some functions every time it changes. However, this input has a value when the page is loaded (in this instance, it is loaded with the user's email address):

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="user@example.com" ng-model="email">
```

Then, in my form controller:

```
$scope.$watch('email', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('Email address has been changed.');
    console.log('Old value: ', oldValue);
    console.log('New value: ', newValue);
}, true);
```

On page load, the above three lines are console logged out, with both `oldValue` and `newValue` being undefined. Then, the form field is left empty.

How can I make Angular keep the existing value of the input and not replace it with nothing when attaching a watch on it?

Comment: Angular isn't changing it. Attaching a watch never changes a value/model. The issue is somewhere else. The watch gets executed the very time the DOM gets displayed, so the log statements are executed that time. Values being undefined suggest that it has not got initialized (with `value="user@example.com"`) properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't with your watch. The problem is that this is the not the expected use of angular. This is the correct procedure.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.email = 'user@example.com';
});
```

It is the databinding itself that is removing your value and it is replacing it with the value of $scope.email, as it should.

If you MUST get the value from the input field itself, then you would need to cache that value before the controller loads. It is the controller itself that causes the problem.

[Here's an example - click](http://jsbin.com/uXeBIM/1/edit) (comment out the `cachedValue` and `$scope.email` to see that the controller/ng-model will blank your value).

The cleanest solution would be to not use ng-model and instead make your own directive that sets the initial value to $scope, then applies the ng-model thus updating as you expect.

I was bored so I wrote the directive.

```
app.directive('initModel', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope[attrs.initModel] = element[0].value;
      element.attr('ng-model', attrs.initModel);
      element.removeAttr('init-model');
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  };
});

<input type="email" name="email" value="user@example.com" init-model="email">
```

[Demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/uXeBIM/2/edit)

Comment: Oh I see, so how can I have the scope pick up the initial value of the input rather than binding initially to undefined?

Comment: @Dwight I don't believe it can. See my updated answer with the live demo on how to cache it and use the cached value.

Comment: @Dwight I further updated my answer including a directive that solves your problem. It's kind of like a wrap for ng-model.

Comment: Thanks, these are both interesting and valid solutions. I hadn't even considered this from a client-side MVC approach, with my model being in the view.

Comment: @Dwight I'm not sure what you meant there. The idea is for a service to pull data from the server via ajax, then your controller binds that data to your views. Then you can update the data in the view and use the controller to submit it back through a service to the server (reversing the process).